# xml2array in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, lxml

the file.xml contains the following data structure:

```
<table>
 <row>
   <x>10</x>
   <t>10:00</t>
</row>
<row>
   <x>20</x>
   <t>10:05</t>
</row>
</table>
```

I have hundred of x,t pairs. I need to plot x vs. t.
I would be thankful if you can help me to solve the problem with python and matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text='''\
<table>
 <row>
   <x>10</x>
   <t>10:00</t>
</row>
<row>
   <x>20</x>
   <t>10:05</t>
</row>
</table>
'''

def convert_t(text):
    a,b=map(float,t.split(':'))
    return a+b/60.0

doc=ET.fromstring(text)
x=[float(x) for x in doc.xpath('//x/text()')]
t=[convert_t(t) for t in doc.xpath('//t/text()')]
plt.plot(x,t)
plt.show()
```

- The above code assumes `10:05` means something like 10 minutes, 5
  seconds. It converts this to a float using `convert_t`.
- A closing `</table>` was added to make the XML valid.